# PHP add time duration in while loop

Tags: php, date, time, addition

I am calculating time duration in while loop by difference of login time and logout time. I want to add all the time duration in a variable and print it out.
The code for this I am using is -

```
$totaltimespent = new DateTime;
$totaltimespent->setTime(0, 0);
$timespent= (strtotime($totaltimespent->format("H:i:s")));

while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['timeoflogin'];
echo $row['logouttime'];

$startTime = new DateTime($row['timeoflogin']);
$endTime = new DateTime($row['logouttime']);
$duration = $startTime->diff($endTime);

echo $duration->format("%H:%I:%S");
$converttime= (strtotime($duration->format("%H:%I:%S")));

$timespent  = date("H:i:s",$converttime+$timespent);
}
echo $timespent;
```

The timeoflogin and logouttime are in format - 05:03:53pm. The $duration is giving right result. I want to add this all duration in varaible and print after while loop. Please help me out.

Comment: what's the output of $duration

Comment: output of $duration is 05:53:26

Comment: It maybe easier to not use `DateTime`, just get the `time()` at the start and end and then format the difference to HH:MM:SS.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the difference you already calculated inside the loop to another `DateTime` object and get the final difference between them.

```php
$totalStart = new DateTime('today'); // this will create it with time 00:00:00
$totalEnd = new DateTime('today'); // we will use this to add the intervals from the loop

while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ...
    $startTime = new DateTime($row['timeoflogin']);
    $endTime = new DateTime($row['logouttime']);
    $duration = $startTime->diff($endTime);
    $totalEnd->add($duration);
    ...
}

$totalTimeSpent = $totalStart->diff($totalEnd);
```

Now all you need to do is format it the way you want to.